# Wikipedia Extract of Aliases

Tags: extract, dump, wikipedia, dbpedia

I know it's possible to extract out Wikipedia content via a dump. However, is it also possible to extract out the search aliases as well?

For instance, that "obama" is an alias of "Barack Obama"?

Comment: Have a look at the source of the page https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Obama&redirect=no (note the &redirect=no) - `#REDIRECT [[Barack Obama]] {{R from surname}}` which is just like the source to any other page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using Wikipedia rather than a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the data you're looking for (in [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) format) in the [redirects datasets](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38#redirects) that were extracted from Wikipedia by [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org).